# Error 403. Wamp Server

Tags: wampserver, http-status-code-403

I have installed wamp server 2.2 
I'm using windows 7

When I am online at that time i'm not able to find localhost using WaMp
its giving me some Forbidden Error..You Don't have Access kind of error.

But when I disconnect my internet connection,  I can get localhost..PHPmyadmin and all feature of WAMP server.

I tried a lot by changing the Apache httpd .conf to Replace `All..."Deny all"` to `"Allow all"`but still, i'm not able to get it online.

Comment: what does putting the ip of the localhost give you? try `127.0.0.1` or whatever you've configured.

Comment: for windows 8 chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945783/wamp-forbidden-error-on-windows-8/20946636#20946636

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Putting server online in contect menu did not help me. If you are using Wamp server 2.2E you will find the lines in your `httpd.conf` file

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

Change them to to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: That was exactly the problem in my case, too. Using the context menu did not change this line.

Comment: In my `httpd.conf` there aren't those lines

Answer (score 8):

Cut and paste:

```
Error 403 Forbidden with phpmyadmin and WAMP Server
Error 403
-----
Forbidden
You do not have permission to access / on this server.
```

Edit the Apache configuration file httpd.conf and find the lines:

```
# onlineoffline tag - don't remove

Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Change them to:

```
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `127.0.0.1` to `::1` or change `Deny from all` to `Allow from all` in the `httpd.conf` file. I have a blog about this error on Windows 8 at http://www.webtrunghieu.info/site?p=21

Comment: I was running into the same problem with windows 8. Your solution just solved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may also have a .htaccess file within your www directory which is causing this error. Be sure to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/host

find the 
 "**#127.0.0.1 localhost**" 
line and uncomment it by removing the # sign

It is possible that you get an 'access denied' message even when you are logged in as an administrator.

To work around that, right click on your file editing software and click run as administrator.

You should be able to save the file then

Localhost should work just fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions posted here, but did not work to get wamp 2.2 started on windows 8 machine. [This link](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,91914) from wamp server forum solved issue. I needed to change "Listen 80" to "Listen 0.0.0.0:80" in httpd.conf file. This may be an issue specific to my machine but the solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

just need put your wampserver online
in tray right-click on wamp icon and **Put Online**