# WAMP forbidden error on windows 8

Tags: wampserver

I'm using windows 8 right now trying to install wamp server but it has forbidden error

I try this and din't work

AllowOverride none
    Require all granted

Answer (score 8):

The reason why it happens is IPV6. Windows 8 is by default an IPV6-first Operating System. How? Well just go to command-prompt and run the command

```
ping localhost
```

You will be getting response from ::1 i.e. the loopback address for IPV6. When you try to connect to the server it uses the port 80 along with IPV6 to locate it.

Check this post here.
http://praveenpuglia.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/setting-up-wamp-server-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 2):

You can see my old guide here http://www.webtrunghieu.info/site/web/solve-the-denied-access-problem-when-using-wamp-server-2-on-windows-8-

Answer (score 2):

goto: 
your-wamp-installation-folder\bin\apache\Apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf

Replace:
 Listen 80

With: 
Listen 0.0.0.0:80

Note: have tested for Apache2.2.21 and 2.2.22