# WAMP WordPress 403 Forbidden

Tags: wordpress, wamp

My file structure is `D:\wamp64\www\wp1`

My wp_options table siteurl and home = `http:\\www.mydomain.com\wp1`

When I'm logged onto the server and I browse to http:\www.mydomain.com\wp1 I see the contents of my index.php

What I need help with is when, I browse to http:\www.mydomain.com\wp1 from a computer other than the server I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I'm pretty certain the issue is file permissions.  I know how to change file permissions, but I don't know what user needs what access to what files/folders.

What user do I need to give what permissions to what files/folders?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running?

Comment: @RiggsFolly WAMPServer 3.0.4

Comment: I tried "Required all granted" suggested here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586720/error-403-wamp-server  But that did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26326982/280785  Needed to update httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf to "Require all granted"