# Xampp does not render php and html

Tags: php, html, xampp, ubuntu-20.10

I've been using WAMP for some time now, creating several projects as well. Everything worked fine.

I've been using a different computer lately that runs on Ububtu 20.10 which has XAMPP instead of WAMP. I had a copy of my www directory from the previous computer that has WAMP. When I try to copy some of the content from the www directory to the htdocs of XAMPP and try to run them on a browser something unusual occurs.

The php files are blank. The browser shows a white page.

The html files throw an 403 error. With the message: "You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server".

Is this common? Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Yes the fix is to give the account which Apache runs under permission to read your HTML files. On Ubuntu it's usually the `www-data` account, I think. If the PHP files are blank, it could be the same error (check the Network tool in your browser if it's not shown on screen) or it could be a PHP error (in which case ensure PHP's error logging is switched on, and then check the error_log file).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 403. Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586720/error-403-wamp-server)

Comment: @thebrownkid the error is in XAMPP in Ubuntu, not WAMP on Windows. It _could_ be the same solution, but equally there's a good chance it isn't.

Comment: You say you copied the file over from some old directory - so go check who the new files belong to now, which user account.

Comment: how you're accessing the website and also where you placed your code? could you please tell me more about it? Thanks.